# Remove substring that occurs multiple times using awk

Tags: linux, string, awk

I need to remove all `\t\t` and all `\n` from my text file.
Snippet of the text.

```
"\t\t\"password\": \"password\","+
"\t\t\"organization\": {\n"+
"\t\t\t\"name\": \"name\""+
"\t\t},"+
"\t\t\"title\": \"title\","+
"\t\t\"phone\": \"999999\","
```

Can anyone help me filter this text out?

My previous solution wasn't very elegant nor efficient, and very verbose.

Comment: Both the solutions work fine but just a thought, it might be worth tackling this issue at the source. It looks like you have something that attempting to"pretty-print" a JSON string with tabs and newlines but the escape characters are not being recognised correctly.

Comment: Actually, the input file is generated from formatted JSON being run thru an escape library. The library outputs the json as Java string(split in concatenated lines of small readable length), but it also escapes and includes the tabs and new lines, which I do not need at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assumed that you're trying to remove the literal `\t` and `\n` characters.

```
$ awk '{gsub(/\\t|\\n/, "")}1' file
"\"password\": \"password\","+
"\"organization\": {"+
"\"name\": \"name\""+
"},"+
"\"title\": \"title\","+
"\"phone\": \"999999\","
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I needed. Tnx

Comment: I had a real fight with the `sub` function... :/

Comment: `gsub` will do the global substitution where the `sub` will do the replacement once per line.

Comment: Yep, than I tried to loop and go back a record... Very messy and inefficient. Stackoverflow to the rescue.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `sed` for simple stream editing, especially for substring removal or substitution:

```
sed -r 's/(\\t\\t|\\n)//g' input.file
```

Comment: Looks like it would be safe enough to match single `\t`, so you can save a couple of characters with `s/\\[tn]//g`

Comment: Sure, you are right! (Having the example data as shown) Nice! :)